# jQuery Reel breaks on IE7/8 with jQuery 1.7+

Tags: jquery

jQuery reel breaks when running using jQuery 1.7 (and up).
Giving the following error :

> Object doesn't support this action Line 3175 (jQuery 1.7 non minified)

Seems to work fine on other browsers (tested on Chrome/FF/Safari).

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: This site doesn't have a lot of mind readers, so post the relevant code.

Comment: even better post a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the line 3175 of jQuery 1.7.1 to "try{ elem[ type ](); }catch(e){}". Now everything is OK. You can try it

Comment: Bad practice of patching the jQuery library core should be avoided at all times. Especially with an exception cover-up like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, rather strange error - triggering `"start"` event somehow bothers IE in jQuery 1.7 enough to throw this obscure error :/

You'll need to rename this event's [trigger](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/blob/master/jquery.reel.js#L209) and [handler](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/blob/master/jquery.reel.js#L242) to use for example `"startreel"` instead of `"start"`. Please, see [this post](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/issues/93#issuecomment-3877792) for more reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

the `type` value was `focus`,

the error was caused (at me) because I wanted to focus a **disabled** button:

So, change this

```
$("#aButtonThatCanBeDisabled").focus(); //this generated the error
```

to this

```
$("#aButtonThatCanBeDisabled:enabled").focus();
```

to make it work well.